# One time "firmware" upgrade script

Tags: networking, kernel, bash, scripts

I was wondering how you could make a script so that on first boot it changes files to a specific parameters?  So it would be like if I just installed a fresh kernel.  I want to run a script once and that script will change `/etc/network/interfaces` to have preset static IPs and to add a message of the day message.  Other items such as creating new users could be added to this script to automate the process a little.

Is it possible to have this script be installed with the kernel so it runs on first boot and then all settings get set?

Comment: "kernel" probably does not mean what you think it means...

Comment: @fkraiem Most likely not.  I am installing a version of ubuntu and would like to make changes automatically versus doing the same process several times for different boards

Answer (score 0):

"@fkraiem Most likely not. I am installing a version of ubuntu and would like to make changes automatically versus doing the same process several times for different boards"

You could write a Bash script that, when run, makes the changes you want. Then you can put it on a USB stick and run it with every new install.

(this is all in a terminal, I use gnome-terminal)
For instance, you could have a template `interfaces` file that is what you want all of them to look like, and then you could write a script file like so: `gedit scriptfile`

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo cp ./interfaces /etc/network/interfaces
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then you could run `chmod +x scriptfile` to make it executable.

Then you put the `scriptfile` and the `interfaces` template file onto a flash drive and when you install Ubuntu on a new "board" you can open the flash drive and run the `scriptfile` and it will replace the current `/etc/network/interfaces` file with the template one and then open it in Gedit for you to customise the IP address.

Comment: Is this process called something specific?  Something that I can begin my web search on.  I am new to scripts and would like to have some good reads on this process.

Comment: What I am recommending is called "Bash scripting" or "Shell scripting". [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/67469/the-beginners-guide-to-shell-scripting-the-basics/) is a guide that might come in handy.

Comment: Ok thank you!  I think I found the exact term or process I was looking for.  Install scripts which are pretty similar to what you are proposing.  Either way the guide will be of much help to me.